# super() in a decorated subclass in Python 2

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.x

I'm trying to use `super` in a subclass which is wrapped in another class using a class decorator:

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    class WrapperClass(object):
        def make_instance(self):
            return cls()
    return WrapperClass

class MyClass(object):
    def say(self, x):
        print(x)

@class_decorator
class MySubclass(MyClass):
    def say(self, x):
        super(MySubclass, self).say(x.upper())
```

However, the call to `super` fails:

```
>>> MySubclass().make_instance().say('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in say
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

The problem is that, when `say` is called, `MySubclass` doesn't refer to the original class anymore, but to the return value of the decorator.

One possible solution would be to store the value of `MySubclass` before decorating it:

```
class MySubclass(MyClass):    
    def say(self, x):
        super(_MySubclass, self).say(x.upper())

_MySubclass = MySubclass

MySubclass = class_decorator(MySubclass)
```

This works, but isn't intuitive and would need to be repeated for each decorated subclass. I'm looking for a way that doesn't need additional boilerplate for each decorated subclass -- adding more code in one place (say, the decorator) would be OK.

**Update:** In Python 3 this isn't a problem, since you can use `__class__` (or the `super` variant without arguments), so the following works:

```
@class_decorator
class MySubclass(MyClass):
    def say(self, x):
        super().say(x.upper())
```

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Python 2.7 for this project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your decorator returns a different class than python (or anyone who uses your code) expects. `super` not working is just one of the many unfortunate consequences:

```
>>> isinstance(MySubclass().make_instance(), MySubclass)
False
>>> issubclass(MySubclass, MyClass)
False
>>> pickle.dumps(MySubclass().make_instance())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.MySubclass'>: it's not the same object as __main__.MySubclass
```

This is why a class decorator should *modify* the class instead of returning a different one. The correct implementation would look like this:

```
def class_decorator(wrapped_cls):
    @classmethod
    def make_instance(cls):
        return cls()

    wrapped_cls.make_instance = make_instance
    return wrapped_cls
```

Now `super` and everything else will work as expected:

```
>>> MySubclass().make_instance().say('hello')
HELLO
```

Comment: Hmm. You're correct that augmenting the existing class would be a better choice, but I don't think that is possible in my original use case. The code I posted is simplified to illustrate the problem. In the real code the decorator returns a descriptor wrapping a class wrapping the original class. Still +1 for illustrating the other pitfalls that I need to be aware of.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker Well, then the problem is your architecture. Replacing a class with a descriptor is just begging for problems, don't you think? Consider the implications for your code's interface - nobody can access the decorated class (since it's no longer bound to any name), effectively making it private. Is that what you want? You should most likely use a different name for the descriptor.

Comment: Aside from the issue in the OP, the architecture has been working perfectly for the intended purpose.  The decorator is easy to use and significantly reduces boilerplate. Its internals are complex, but that's OK for me as far as it does its job ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because at the time when MySubclass.say() is called, the global symbol MySubclass no longer refers to what's defined in your code as 'class MySubclass'. It is an instance of WrapperClass, which isn't in any way related to MySubclass.

If you are using Python3, you can get around this by NOT passing any arguments to 'super', like this:

```
super().say(x.upper())
```

I don't really know why you use the specific construct that you have, but it does look strange that a sub-class of MyClass that defines 'say()' - and has itself a 'say()' method in the source code would have to end up as something that does not have that method - which is the case in your code.

Note you could change the `class WrapperClass` line to make it read

```
class WrapperClass(cls):
```

this will make your wrapper a sub-class of the one you just decorated. This doesn't help with your super(SubClass, self) call - you still need to remove the args (which is OK only on Python3), but at least an instance created as x=MySubclass() would have a 'say' method, as one would expect at first glance.

EDIT: I've come up with a way around this, but it really looks odd and has the disadvantage of making the 'wrapped' class **know** that it is being wrapped (and it becomes reliant on that, making it unusable if you remove the decorator):

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    class WrapperClass(object):
        def make_instance(self):
            i = cls()
            i._wrapped = cls
            return i
    return WrapperClass

class MyClass(object):
    def say(self, x):
        print(x)

@class_decorator
class MySubclass(MyClass):
    def say(self, x):
        super(self._wrapped, self).say(x.upper())

# make_instance returns inst of the original class, non-decorated i = MySubclass().make_instance() i.say('hello')
```

In essence, `_wrapped` saves a class reference as it was *at declaration time*, consistent with using the regular super(this_class_name, self) builtin call.

Comment: As I've written [in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860397/super-in-a-decorated-subclass-in-python-2/51861341#comment90674206_51860788), I'm not using these classes in the traditional way. They are not intended to be instantiated directly, instead they are used as an elegant way to significantly reduce boilerplate in certain situations. Your remark regarding Python 3 is on point (see my previous update), but unfortunately I'm stuck with Python 2.7 for this project.